# Reformat JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**Problem**

I have the following example json data which is not formatted how I need it:

```
"stations": {
    "st1": "station 1",
    "st2": "station 2",
    "st3": "Station 3",
}
```

**Question**

How can I reformat the data to be:

```
"stations": [
  {
    "id": "st1",
    "name": "station 1",
  },
  {
    "id": "st2",
    "name": "station 2",
  },
  {
    "id": "st3",
    "name": "station 3",
  }
]
```

**Tried**

I tried to simply log the data to test first but am struggling how to actually even iterate between the key/value pairs as they are essentially strings

This is what i tried:

```
$.get( '/js/ajax/tube-data.json', function( data ) {

    $.each(data.stations, function () {
        // I was expecting st1, st2, st3 to show in the console
        // but got first letter of each station 
        console.log(this[0]) 
    });

}).error(function() {console.log(arguments) });
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you checked [the documentation for `$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)?

Comment: [`var arr = [];
Object.keys(obj.stations).forEach(function(key) {
    arr.push({
        id: key,
        name: obj.stations[key]
    });
});`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/6dfoz1sp/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will do.

```js
var object = { stations: { st1: "station 1", st2: "station 2", st3: "Station 3", } };

object.stations = Object.keys(object.stations).map(function (k) {
    return { id: k, name: object.stations[k] };
})

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Exactly what I meant, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. Its a plain vanilla code for doing the same:

```
var b=[];
for(key in a) {
    console.info(key);
    var x = {};
    x[key] = a[key];
    b.push(x);
}
console.info("b: ", b);
```